# Apps Script | How to Archive Specific Rows Based On Values In Column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to Archive specific rows on the "Referral Logs" sheet. The criteria I am looking for is in the "H" column.
[image: Referral Logs Sheet]

If a value in that column equals "Yes", "No", or "Half", I want the associated row to be archived in the "Referral Archives" sheet.
[image: Referral Archives Sheet]

### **My Code**

```
function archiveReferrals() {
  // Set up the sheet, and ranges.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Referral Logs');
  var a = ss.getSheetByName('Referral Archives');
  var r = s.getRange("H2:H");

  if(r.getValue() == "Yes" || r.getValue() == "Half" || r.getValue() == "No") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = a;

    // Move the row to the archive
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);

    // Delete the row
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

**The Problem:**
The problem with this code is that it would have to be manually ran each time you want to log something. This is inefficient, and doesn't have any automation.

**Expected Outcome:**
The expected outcome is to have all of the "Yes", "Half", and "No" results automatically move to the "Referrals Archive" sheet **weekly**. This could be a filter or a for loop, any way to make it more automated is ideal.

And because it is a form, those rows in the "Referral Logs" sheet that are now empty because they have been moved, would need to be deleted.

I really appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check whether the value of a cell in
  the range **H2:H** is included  in the list: `["Yes","Half","No"]`,
- then take advantage of the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to iterate over all the **H2:H** cells, find the cells that fulfil step 1 and get the row index,
- finally, remove the rows from the original file based on the previous step. To achieve that you can only delete them backwards by using the [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method, otherwise the index is going to be affected by the deleted rows.

I also added a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) in case there is not data to process. Namely, none of the H values is equal to the `["Yes","Half","No"]`.

### Solution:

```
function archiveReferrals() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const s = ss.getSheetByName('Referral Logs');
  const a = ss.getSheetByName('Referral Archives');
  const values = s.getRange("H2:H").getValues().flat();
  const checks = ["Yes","Half","No"];
  const rowsDelete = [];
  const valuesMove = [];
  
  values.forEach((val,index)=>{
                 
     if (checks.includes(val)){
        valuesMove.push(s.getRange(index+2,1,1,8).getValues().flat());
        rowsDelete.push(index+2);
      }});
  
  try{
     a.getRange(a.getLastRow()+1,1,valuesMove.length,valuesMove[0].length).setValues(valuesMove);
     rowsDelete.reverse().forEach(rd=>s.deleteRow(rd));
  }

  catch(e){console.log("no data to process")};          
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however is there any way to make this a loop instead of an onEdit function? I want the referrals to be there for a week instead of instantly moved to the "Referral Archives" on edit. I plan to set up a trigger with the function that would be ran weekly.

Comment: I made a change to the post to hopefully clarify this more.

Comment: @TylerShannon check my updated answer and let me know if it worked for you.